# Sorting multidimensional array based on third array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to sort a multidimensional array in alphabetical order based on the `label` key and still keep the original `category` key. I have tried using `uasort` but that doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a[0]['label'] <=> $b[0]['label'];
});
```

Can somebody help me out?

I have the following array:

```
$array = Array 
(
    [Bier] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [value] => KIT 1
                [label] => Amstel Tray 12 x 50cl
                [picture] => amstel-tray-24-0_5.jpg
            )
            [1] => Array
            (
                [value] => 2
                [label] => Heineken Krat 24 x 30cl
                [picture] => heineken-krat-24-flesjes.jpg
            )
            [2] => Array
            (
                [value] => 4
                [label] => Amstel Tray 24 x 50cl
                [picture] => amstel-tray-24-0_5.jpg
            )

        )
    )
    [Second Category] => [..]
    [Third Category] => [..]
    [..] => [..]
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to sort `Bier` against `Second Category` or `$arr['Bier'][0]` against `$arr['Bier'][1]` ? You `uasort` does the former.

Comment: @Bryan I know, but thats not what I want. I'm trying to sort `$arr[Bier][0]['label']` in an alphabetical order. So the first one will be the `[value] => KIT 1`, the second `[value] => 4` etc.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, added an answer I think solves your issue if you're still stuck.

Comment: @Bryan I already figured it out, but thanks for your response anyway! Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you're sorting the outer array by the value of the labels on the inner arrays when it seems like what you actually want is to sort the items in each array. Try looping through the array and sorting as you go.

```
foreach($array as &$arr) {
    uasort($arr, function($a, $b) {
        return $a['label'] <=> $b['label'];
    });
}
```

Notice that I'm looping over the reference also, if you don't do this, the items in the original array won't be sorted.

Comment: That seems to do the trick! But is that the cleanest way? It feels so weird to each an array only just for reordering the position

Comment: You can use array walk or map if you think it looks cleaner, but you're reordering the children array items, not the outer most items, so it needs to be done.